# AVD with Play Store, can I make Google Maps view work?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

If I create an AVD without Play Store, "Hardware - GLES 2.0" is selected by default for Graphics, and Google Maps view (not the Google Maps app) works fine.

But if I create an AVD with PlayStore, the graphics option is disabled (greyed "Automatic" is selected). The Google Maps app works fine, but when I run my app with a Google Maps view, the view is empty and there is an error message on the Logcat.

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
```

I have tried changing the OpenGL settings in the Advanced tab of the emulator settings, but none of them worked. Since the Google Maps app is displaying the map just fine on the same AVD, I guess the Google Maps view is mistakenly thinking that it cannot display the map on the AVD.

Is there any way to make the Google Maps view work on the AVD?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a coincidence or the Google's Android team read this, but the latest update to the emulator (27.1.10), which was released a few days ago, has fixed this problem. I did not do anything but updating the emulator, and now Google Maps view is correctly displayed.